# icacls.exe doesn't show that ACL was inherited (I)

Tags: windows, permissions, icacls

I noticed different behaviour of icacls.exe on two machines with Windows 10:

Windows 10 Version 1809 (OS Build 17763.678)

```
> echo "test" > file
> icacls.exe file
file NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(F)
     BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)
     W10A\dev:(F)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

> Get-Acl file | Format-List


Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\dev\file
Owner  : W10A\dev
Group  : W10A\None
Access : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
         BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
         W10A\dev Allow  FullControl
Audit  :
Sddl   : O:S-1-5-21-3626095386-1962481266-1351198716-1003G:S-1-5-21-3626095386-1962481266-1351198716-513D:(A;ID;FA;;;SY)(A;ID;FA;;;BA)(A;ID;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3626095386-1962481266-1351198716-1003)
```

Windows 10 Version 1803 (OS Build 17134.950)

```
> echo "test" > file
> icacls.exe file
file NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
     BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
     W10B\dev:(I)(F)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

>  Get-Acl file | Format-List


Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\dev\file
Owner  : W10B\dev
Group  : W10B\None
Access : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
         BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
         W10B\dev Allow  FullControl
Audit  :
Sddl   : O:S-1-5-21-1873008998-2522687245-1987858218-1006G:S-1-5-21-1873008998-2522687245-1987858218-513D:AI(A;ID;FA;;;
         SY)(A;ID;FA;;;BA)(A;ID;FA;;;S-1-5-21-1873008998-2522687245-1987858218-1006)
```

The file is local in both cases. `Get-Acl` shows that entries are inherited (`ID`) as expected. Why does `icacls` hide the information on the former machine?
Interestingly, in the former case if I add any entry to the ACL (e.g. deny access to user X), the next call to icacls.exe shows `(I)` flags.

Comment: Does this happen on a local NTFS filesystem or over the network? What do other tools such as PowerShell `get-acl` show? What is the parent directory's ACL?

Comment: @grawity: I updated the question.